# GetItem xml request using makeEwsRequestAsync() in Outlook for Mac has stopped returning a response

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Outlook for Mac: 16.24 (19041401)

I'm making a getItem request using makeEwsRequestAsync in Outlook for Mac and the callback does not contain a response, (status == succeeded, value is null). The same request from OWA/Outlook 2016 contains a valid xml response. I'm using the GetItem request to retrieve a changekey.

Why is there a difference in behavior here?

XML GetItem request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetItem>
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:BodyType>Text</t:BodyType>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:ItemIds>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGNlYjE1NWU4LTU1NmItNDdhYy04OTZiLWZmM2UwNjFkZjA1YwBGAAAAAACQR9mC/O1ETaOK/jgMPXmgBwCLsR3BxFcKQIBIOhhvOBA4AAAAAAEJAACLsR3BxFcKQIBIOhhvOBA4AAPI6G5DAAA="/>
            </m:ItemIds>
        </m:GetItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [known issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/433#issuecomment-501554417) acknowledged by Outlook for mac team and it is fixed in newer version of Outlook.(16.26+)